# Ensuring that all polygons on a map are visible

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapely

I have a map with some 4000 districts on it. I produce the map using matplotlib and save it as a png. Each district is represented in most cases by a Polygon, which I colour in based on the data I wish to present. I've noticed that it is possible for one polygon on my map to hide another polygon. This is dependant on the order in which the polygons are added to the map. I wish to figure out which districts can be hidden in this manner. The only way I believe I can do this is to test each of the 4,000 polygons individually as follows:

- Place the polygon under test on the map using the colour red,
- then place all adjacent polygons on map using white.
- Save as png
- check for red pixels in png

Do this sound like a reasonable approach?

The code below demonstrated the issue:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('svg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from cartopy import crs
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

west, south, east, north = (-10.66, 51.39, -0.73382454, 60.85432117)
extent = [west, east, south, north]

data = {("Queen's Co.", 'Maryborough Rural'): 0,("Queen's Co.", 'Maryborough Urban'): 1,}

polygons = [
(("Queen's Co.", 'Maryborough Urban'), Polygon(((-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397), (-7.298121532671447, 53.04251879703033), (-7.293768369192515, 53.03380932328098), (-7.300693076752503, 53.02996865969516), (-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397)))),

(("Queen's Co.", 'Maryborough Rural'), Polygon([(-7.262936925807475, 53.0243340481189), (-7.261790185796011, 53.01326260447617), (-7.332505479924034, 52.99321050796248), (-7.31380510872903, 53.04836322204095), (-7.297755293365016, 53.04446881216628), (-7.294050788944783, 53.06224313202594), (-7.230549378949404, 53.04023366246838),  (-7.262936925807475, 53.0243340481189)],
        holes = [[(-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397), (-7.300693076752503, 53.02996865969516), (-7.293768369192515, 53.03380932328098), (-7.298121532671447, 53.04251879703033), (-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397)]]
    )),
]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs.Mercator())
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=crs.PlateCarree())

for rd, polygon in polygons:
    col = (1, 0, 0) if data[rd] == 1 else (0, 0, 0)

    ax.add_patch(
        PolygonPatch(polygon, facecolor=col, edgecolor=col, zorder=1, lw=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    )

fig.savefig("./sanity.png")
plt.close()
```

The above code shows only one black polygon. Changing the order of the items in the `polygon` list will result in a red and black polygon. Changing the extent so that the polygons become bigger within the png will also result in the red polygon becoming visible, for example:

```
west, south, east, north = (-7.4, 52.9, -6.94, 53.1)
```

I believe I need a linewidth of 1 and for the edge to be the same colour as the polygon itself in order to avoid glitches becoming visible between the polygons. So this is why I have chosen these values.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably quicker (and png resolution independent) to test if the two paths intersect or enclose each other. Just using matplotlib (although I imagine shapely has similar functionality):

```
from matplotlib.path import Path

urban = Path([(-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397), (-7.298121532671447, 53.04251879703033), (-7.293768369192515, 53.03380932328098), (-7.300693076752503, 53.02996865969516), (-7.305110014156934, 53.03454727879397)], closed=True)

rural = Path([(-7.262936925807475, 53.0243340481189), (-7.261790185796011, 53.01326260447617), (-7.332505479924034, 52.99321050796248), (-7.31380510872903, 53.04836322204095), (-7.297755293365016, 53.04446881216628), (-7.294050788944783, 53.06224313202594), (-7.230549378949404, 53.04023366246838),  (-7.262936925807475, 53.0243340481189)], closed=True)

print(urban.intersects_path(rural, filled=True)) # If filled is True, then this also returns True if one path completely encloses the other (i.e., the paths are treated as filled).
# True
```

To completely cover a polygon A with another polygon B, the area of B has to be strictly larger. So by computing the areas, you can quickly determine which polygon should be plotted on top (the smaller).

Comment: @ Couldn't a few smaller polys cover a bigger one?

Comment: Sure, but in that case, you cannot show all polygons simultaneously on a single canvas anyway.

Comment: None of my polygons overlap in terms of their geometry. The problems are when polygons get converted to pixels and have to compete for space.

Comment: But surely the issue is then solely attributable to the non-zero line width? Do you still have overlaps when you set the linewidth to zero / linecolor to None? The line is centered on the path, so with non-zero linewidth overlaps would indeed be expected.

Comment: But setting the linewidth to zero results in visible gaps between the polygons.

Comment: Anyway, as you shrink the size of the png, the polygons are forced more and more to compete with each other for space. If the png was 1x1 pixel then its obvious that you cant represent all the polygons, irrespective of linewidth of the edge.